# Send Ctrl+C to process

Tags: c#, winapi

I have to send to send Ctrl+C to console process created from my C# application. I have found a lot of similar threads but haven't found a solutaion (tried CreateProcess, GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent, etc.). Is there any working example?

Answer (score 0):

Don't even trouble yourself with all this `Process` nonsense.

[MedallionShell](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionShell#stopping-a-command) can send `Ctrl + C` signals and is implemented as multi-platform, so you can forget all the Windows interop stuff you see out there. `MedallionShell` does it for you. It also makes every other aspect of interacting with a process completely trivial and includes `Task / TPL` and `CancellationToken` support. Also also, it's `MIT Licensed`!

It's pretty easy to use:

```
var command = Command.Run("dotnet", "run", "--project", "C:\MyRepo\MyProj\MyProj.csproj");

// Do what you gotta do. hey, I ain't juding.

await command.TrySignalAsync(CommandSignal.ControlC);
```

Aaand PRESTO! You've now managed the entire lifecycle of process without any bonkers windows-specific shenanigans.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The key `CRTL + C` is ASCII 3 (in decimal)

```
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Sort.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
myProcess.Start();
StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;
myStreamWriter.WriteLine(inputText);
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work. I write 3 to input stream but without any success.

Comment: how did u write 3 to stream? "3" or `char.ConvertFromUtf32(3)`. vote up if this works :)

Comment: I just recorded byte 3. I also tried char.ConvertFromUtf32(3) - it doesn't work also.

Comment: char.ConvertFromUtf32(3) works perfectly. I used it for closing GPRS connection.